# how to return an array of strings from asnycktask to String[] in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

sorry i think my question was too confusing and too much code so i am editing it and make it shorter.

So basically i created a external Asynctask called BackgroundWorker.java and then it was called in another activity called picture.java

Ok so below is my AsyncTask code (backgroundWorker.java). i was able to get JSON file and get to extract Json.getString['image_link'] and it was shown in the alertdialog. i want to copy the value of Json.getString['image_link'] into private String[] mStrings= that are located in another activity called picture.java.

```
    if (type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            // execute the data
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            // close all connection
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            // get the return
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                result += line;
                sb.append(line+"\n");
                String finalJson = sb.toString();

                JSONObject parentobject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentobject.getJSONArray("people");
                stringbuff = new StringBuffer();


                for(int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    placename = finalObject.getString("name");
                    placelink = finalObject.getString("image_link");
                    stringbuff.append(placename + "  " + placelink + "," + "\n");

                }


            }

            // close buffered reader
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

picture.java have a variable called mString = private String[] mStrings. it does not have anything in it, i wanted to copy the value of Json.getString['image_link'] into it. i did not know how to do this please help. i really need to do this

Comment: Just a side comment. Your doInBackground method is really, really long and does lots of things. Generally, a good rule is to keep methods short and also make sure that they only do one thing. Either they manipulate something, or they return some type of data. It's much easier to work with if that's the case! It also makes them much easier to read for us on SO :)

Comment: sorry that i made u have to read all those code, i just started recently in android programming, so i am not really sure what i am doing. i appreciate all the advice that i can get.

Comment: Oh gosh, it's no worry at all. I just wanted to offer some advice I wish people gave me when I was starting haha. Just have fun and learn! It's okay if your functions are a little larger ;)

Comment: thanks kris, if you dont mind could you take a look at my question again, i edit it. could u tell me if it was better thank before? and maybe help me with my little problem :)

Comment: The easiest way is just to make the AsyncTask an inner class of the Activity.   If you want to keep the AsyncTask separate so that it can be used in multiple activities, you'll need to use a LocalBroadcast or EventBus.  See here for more info about using a LocalBroadcast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080141/how-can-android-service-update-the-ui-of-the-activity-that-started-it