# Resuming download progress after UI is destroyed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I have an app that allows a user to do multiple downloads.

1. For example, the user clicks an icon, a fragment comes up starting the download and shows the progress by updating the progress bar every second.
2. The user can press the back button, the fragment is destroyed and can click a different button, downloading a different item in parallel.
3. If the user goes back to click the first icon, and the download is still ongoing, the requirement is that the progress bar will be shown automatically so that the user knows the download is not done yet.

My problem is #3 where if the user presses back and the Asynctask loses the UI, the progress updates stop on resume. How do I get the updates for the correct item being downloaded, since the feature is multiple parallel downloads?

Currently, I am wrapping the AsyncTask in a fragment to retain the instance. Could anyone advise on what is the proper way to do this (minimizing memory leaks as much as possible)?

```
class DownloadTaskFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mCallbacks: TaskCallbacks? = null
    private var mTask: DummyTask? = null


    interface TaskCallbacks {
        fun onPreExecute()
        fun onProgressUpdate(progress: Int)
        fun onCancelled()
        fun onPostExecute()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true

        mTask = DummyTask(this)
        mTask!!.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
    }

    fun setCallBackInterface(taskCallback: TaskCallbacks) {
        mCallbacks = taskCallback
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        mCallbacks = null
    }


    class DummyTask// only retain a weak reference to the activity
    internal constructor(context: DownloadTaskFragment) : AsyncTask<String, Int, Int>() {

        private val reference: WeakReference<DownloadTaskFragment> = WeakReference(context)
        private var mCallbacks: TaskCallbacks? = reference.get()!!.mCallbacks


        override fun onPreExecute() {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks!!.onPreExecute()
            }
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): Int {
            var i = 0
            while (!isCancelled && i < 80) {
                SystemClock.sleep(100)
                publishProgress(i)
                i++
            }

            return 1
        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks!!.onProgressUpdate(values[0]!!)
            }
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Int?) {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks!!.onPostExecute()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled() {
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks!!.onCancelled()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you pls tell what should be the behavior if user kills the app?

Comment: The download should still continue in the background even if the user kills the app.

Comment: you can make service for this task which will help you to keep the task going on background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make sure that the task continues in the background (especially with the increased restrictions in API 26+) you will need to create a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). Note: you MUST show an accompanying notification (this can simply be a progress bar)

As a foreground service, your task will run separately from the main UI and therefore will not be effected by any changes to the UI. You can also update the UI from the service (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080141/how-can-android-service-update-the-ui-of-the-activity-that-started-it) for more information)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) for this.
Guidelines on the usage of it can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).

If you need to communicate between WorkManager and Fragment you can use `LiveData<T>` for this.
[Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#7) is the article which describe the case.